Setup Di2 R9150 front derailleur
I changed my front rings from Shimano to another brand. Therefore the front derailleur does not fit right and needs to be adjusted.
First things I did is fetch the official Shimano documentation (https://si.shimano.com/en/pdfs/dm/R9150/DM-R9150-09-ENG.pdf). Schematics are very clear but… to which gear the derailleur should be set to start alignment? Both extremes (lower gear and upper gear) have me weird results. I ended up adjusting the H screw on feel.
In what position should I set the derailleur to start the setup?

A different brand chainring (of the same size and roundness) should fit the same. Is it an oval chainring? A larger one?

It fits, only it does need slight adjustments. As I said, I manage to adjust the derailleur, I did a couple of good rides with no problem not rubbing.
